# Database for user Accounts ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, ionic-framework

I need to incorporate a simple user profile for each person who uses my ionic android app. That way they can login and access or edit personal information unique to their personal accounts.

I've been browsing all over the net for a day, and especially the ionic documentation for any info on how to make such a feature on my app. I can do that using php and mysql but don't know about ionic's approach. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the devices `localstorage`?

You can quite easily store variables and objects in the device using the following code.

```
$window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(object);
var object = $window.localStorage[key];
```

Personally I set these up in a factory so they can be accessed a lot easier across the App like follows

```
.factory("localStorage", ["$window", function($window) {
    return {
            set: function(key, value) {
                $window.localStorage[key] = value;
            },
            get: function(key, defaultValue) {
                return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
            },
            setObject: function(key, object) {
                $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringfy(object);
            },
            getObject: function(key) {
                return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key]);
            },
            remove: function(key) {
                $window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
            }
      }
}
```

then inject the factory into your controller and run `localStorage.setObject("users", userArray);`